# How to sync code between team but only commit important stuff to main repo

Tags: git, version-control

We're working on quite big project and decided use GIT for version control.
I've got question about how to organize our workflow:

We intend to push only important stuff to repo, as commit messages must have good description of changes, either ticket, or but or feature label and just well formatted.

However, sometimes we want to sync stuff between team internally. For example frontend guy want to start working on some view, but he don't have controller & action setup, so dev guy will quickly create this, and send it somehow to frontend guy. But we don't want such commits to trash our changelog.

How this should be set in order to archive propper workflow.

tl,dr
- want to push only important, well documented changes to main repo, 
- have way to sync all changes with team

Maybe I am missing something, but I just look for hint how to organize our workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use topic branches either in the main repo or separate repos (one per developer which is readable by all devs though).

For topic branches in the main repo, you could name them like 'devname/topicname' so it's easy to see to whom it belongs.

For topic branches in separate repos (you should never work on the main branch anyway unless you are integrating something from another branch), I'd use the same naming but without the 'devname/' part.

---

You might also want to have a look at [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) - I've never used it, but it looks interesting. It's basically also using topic branches but mainly uses a different policy regarding merges (no fast-forwards etc).

---

Here [at work](http://indico-software.org/) we are doing it like this:

There is a master repository where only two people () ever push to. Every developer clones from this repo and then creates two remote repositories on shared space (we do it using a shared filesystem (AFS), but a SSH-accessible host would do the job, too).

One of the repos is considered "private"; it's mainly a backup to push unfinished things to (remember: "make small commits and commit often").
Rebasing and force-pushing to this repository is fine since nobody will ever merge from it (actually, here it's even in a private folder not accessibly by anyone else).

The other repo is the "public" one accessible by all developers. When asking one of the gatekeepers to merge, he'll fetch from the developer's public repository, rebase locally and then fast-forward-merge the branch. In the public branches (which are also available to the [general public](http://indico-software.org/repo)) rebasing is usually not performed unless needed e.g. to perform a big rebase so reduce the workload of the gatekeeper.
Of course any rebasing in those repos is usually not a good thing since they are public but we consider it OK since it's very unlikely that someone actually bases work on a non-master branch in one of these repos.

Answer (score 0):

The developer work either on topic branches or on per-dev branches or per-dev topic branches or one common branch which is not the "main" one, whatever fits your workflow best, and then someone appoitned for his or her acute sense of responsibility cherry-picks and/or merges important stuff into your main branch.